# create drop down list from json

Tags: javascript, json, drop-down-menu

I have a json in this form:

```
{"COLUMNS":["ID", "Name"],"DATA":
[ 
  ["1","Joe"],
  ["2", "Sam"],
  ["3", "Doug"],
]
}
```

and I was looking for an example of how to create a drop down list from this data in javascript but all the examples of json/dropdown list the json is in a different format.  I haven't worked with javascript much or json data at all so I'm not sure about where to start.  Can anyone point me in the direction of a great tutorial or examples? Thanks.

Comment: can u please explain how you are getting this json response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var JSON = {
        "COLUMNS":["ID", "Name"],
        "DATA": [ 
            ["1","Joe"],
            ["2", "Sam"],
            ["3", "Doug"]
        ]
    }, select = document.getElementById("selector");
    for (var i = 0, at = JSON.DATA[i], id = at[0], name = at[1]; i < JSON.DATA.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = id;
        option.textContent = name;
        select.appendChild(option);
    };
};
```

Please make sure that if your JSON is in string form, that you parse it first using `JSON.parse();`

The HTML:

```
<select id="selector"></select>
```

The JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/su7sr/1

Comment: Never heard of it. Was just answering the OP's question.

Comment: your json string is not valid json ,Are you generating from yourself?

Comment: {
    "Table": [
        {
            "stateid": "2",
            "statename": "Tamilnadu"
        },
        {
            "stateid": "3",
            "statename": "Karnataka"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: @Aarif Just using what the OP gave me to work with. The JSON in my code is now valid. I checked it.

Comment: this is the valid json format,replace stateid with your ID and statename with your NAME

Comment: What do you mean? Everything works. Just check the fiddle. @Aarif

Comment: please make sure this javascript code is in  $().ready(function () {});

Comment: @Aarif jQuery is not tagged. Used `window.onload` instead.

Comment: @Aarif The code given here does not need to be point perfect. It gives the idea of how to use JSON to create drop-downs. The OP can take the idea and see to it that his/her JSON is perfect. Why are you wasting time on such stuff?

Comment: @Pushpesh I'm sure I answered before he could so now he is picking at every aspect of my code. No hurt feeling though, because it works.

Comment: I took a look at the jsfiddle example and this works perfectly when I added extra data that I left out of my question. I appreciate the help.

Comment: oh sorry yar i thought this code was from the person who has posted this question

Comment: i asked him for the code he has tried and i found your code as her code

Comment: The initialization in for loop is only executed once.  The "at" variable never gets updated to the next element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I thing that correct JS will be:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var JSON = {
        "COLUMNS":["ID", "Name"],
        "DATA": [ 
            ["1","Joe"],
            ["2", "Sam"],
            ["3", "Doug"]
        ]
    }, select = document.getElementById("selector");
    for (var i = 0; i < JSON.DATA.length; i++) {
    var at = JSON.DATA[i], id = at[0], name = at[1];
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = id;
        option.textContent = name;
        select.appendChild(option);
    };
};
```