# Sending list for select box from servlet to JSP using AJAX

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I am getting dynamic data for Company name select box. Based on those values I need to populate data for Business area select box. For that I am calling a servlet through AJAX.

In the servlet I am getting list of business areas based on company name, but I can't understand how I can pass this list to my JSP code.

I am getting dynamic data for select box like below:

Company Name:

```
<select id="company_id" onchange="getBusinessArea()">
    <option selected="selected">--Select One--</option>
    <% for (String txt : new ExtractDao().getCompanies()) {%>
    <option><%=txt%></option>
    <%}%>
</select>
```

By using the above company name i need to populate data for below select box:

```
Business Area :
 <select>
    <option><option>
 </select>
```

I am calling my servlet using AJAX:

```
function getBusinessArea() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("company_id");
        var selectedNode = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
        window.alert(selectedNode);
        var xmlhttp;
        var companyData = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ExtractController?companyName="
                + selectedNode;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        window.alert(companyData);
        xmlhttp.open("GET", companyData, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
            if (http_request.status == 200) {
                alert(http_request.responseText);
            } else {
                alert('There was a problem with the request.');
            }
        }
    }
```

My Servlet code:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        ExtractService extService = null;
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        String companyName = request.getParameter("companyName");
        extService = new ExtractService();
        List<String> bList = extService.getBusinessAreas(companyName);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me show how I can populate data for business area select box?

Comment: You need to send your data as json & parse it on client side. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647065/create-drop-down-list-from-json)